# DataTable Editor Validation: check if value already exists depending on value of other column

Tags: javascript, arrays, datatables

I'm using DataTable and Editor and I would like to check if a specific value already exists in column_02 but only for the rows with a specific value in column_01. So more specific, e.g. I would like to check if value_04 is in column_02 but only for the rows with 1 in column_01. If the value already exists, an error message should appear.

```
column_01 | column_02
1,value_03
1,value_02
1,value_01
3,value_01
5,value_04
```

The below checks if the value is in the whole column_02 (but not depending on values in column_01):

```
editor_table.on( 'preSubmit', function ( e, o, action ) {
    if ( action !== 'remove' ) {

        var getcolumn_01 = editor_table.field( 'table.column_01' );
        var getcolumn_02 = editor_table.field( 'table.column_02' );

        var indexcolumn_01 = table_table.column( 0 ).data().indexOf(getcolumn_01.val());
        var indexcolumn_02 = table_table.column( 1 ).data().indexOf(getcolumn_02.val());

        if ( ! getcolumn_02.isMultiValue() ) {

            if ( indexcolumn_02 >= 0 ) {
                    getcolumn_02.error( 'Name selected already exist in Busket!' );
            }
        }

        // If any error was reported, cancel the submission so it can be corrected
        if ( this.inError() ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
} );  

// console.log(getcolumn_01);  = 1
// console.log(getcolumn_02);  = value_04
```

Comment: This is not fun to answer without a demo of what you have so far. http://live.datatables.net/ / https://jsfiddle.net/